# counting of the occurrence of substrings

Tags: c++, c

Is there an efficient algorithm to count the total number of occurrence of a sub-string `X` in a longer string `Y` ?

To be more specific, what I want is, the total number of ways of selecting A.size() elements from B such that there exists a permutation of the selected elements that matches B.

An example is as follows: search the total number of occurrence of `X=AB` in string `Y=ABCDBFGHIJ` ?

The answer is 2 : first A and second B, and first A and 5-th B.

I know we can generate all permutations of the long string (which will be `N!` length `N` strings `Y`) and use KMP algorithm to search/count the occurrence of `X` in `Y`.

Can we do better than that ?

The original problem I try to solve is as follows: let's say we have a large matrix M of size r by c (r and c in the range of 10000's). Given a small matrix P of size a by b (a and b are in the range of 10's). Find the total number of different selections of a rows and b columns of M (this will give us an a by b "submatrix" H) so that there exists a permutation of the rows and columns of H that gives us a matrix which matches P.

I think once I can solve 1-D case, 2-D may follow the solution.

After research, I find out that this is a sub-graph isomorphism problem and it is NP-hard. There are some algorithms solve this efficiently. One can google it and see many papers on this.

Comment: Obvious first step: remove all the characters from Y that aren't in X. In your example, you'd change Y to `ABB`. From there it doesn't seem to be much more than a matter of counting.

Comment: That's not exactly a "substring", which is generally considered to be a consecutive sequence... more like an "ordered subset" or something...

Comment: Agree with @twalberg.  If you can clarify what _exactly_ you mean by sub-string, that would make it possible to answer the question.  So, is it true then that your definition of substring(_s_) is that if  X=AB then the sub-strings are "A", "B" and "AB"?

Comment: I think what I want is, the total number of ways of selecting A.size() elements from B such that there exists a permutation of the selected elements that matches B.

Answer (score 1):

After having read, then re-read the question (at @Charlie 's suggestion), I have concluded that these answers are not addressing the real issue.  I have concluded also that I still do not know exactly what the issue is, but if OP answer's my questions and clarifies the issue, then I will come back and make a better attempt at addressing it.  For now, I will leave this as a place holder...

To find occurrences of a letter or other character:

```
char buf[]="this is the string to search";
int i, count=0, len;
len = strlen(buf);
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    if(buf[i] == 's') count++;
}
```

or, using `strtok()`, find occurrences of a sub-string:
Not pretty, brute force method.
// strings to search

```
char str1[]="is";
char str2[]="s";
int count = 0;
char buf[]="this is the string to search";
char *tok;
tok = strtok(buf, str1);
while(tok){
    count++;
    tok = strtok(NULL, str1);
}
tok = strtok(buf, str2);
while(tok){
    count++;
    tok = strtok(NULL, str2);
}
```

count should contain the total of occurrences of "s", + occurrences of "is"

***[EDIT]***
First, let me ask for a technical clarification of your question, given A = "AR", B = "START", the solutions would be "A", "R" and "AR", in this case all found in the 3rd and 4th letters of B.  Is that correct?.  If so, that's easy enough.  You can do that with some small modifications and additions to what I have already done above. And if you have questions about that code, I would be happy to address them if I can.

The second part is your real question: Searching with better than, or at least with the same efficiency as the ***[KMP algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)*** - that's the real trick.  If *choosing the best approach* is the real question, then some Google searching is in order. Because once you find, and settle on the best approach (efficiency >= KPM) to solving the sub-string search, then the implementation will be a set of simple steps ([if you give it enough time](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TimeToMakeItShort)), possibly, but not necessarily using some of the same components of C used above.  (Pointer manipulation will be faster than using the string functions I think.) But these techniques are just implementation, and should always follow a good design.  Here are a few Google searches to help you get started with a search...  (you may have already been to some of these)

***[Validating KMP](http://www.ii.uni.wroc.pl/~lje/Papers/piprimjournal.pdf)***
***[KMP - Can we do better?](http://www.cmi.ac.in/~kshitij/talks/kmp-talk/kmp.pdf)***
***[KMP - Defined](http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/kmpen.htm)***
***[KMP - Improvements using Fibonacci String](http://par.cse.nsysu.edu.tw/~algo/paper/paper11/A2_2.pdf)***

If once you have made your algorithm selection, and begin to implement your design, you have questions about techniques, or coding suggestions, Post them.  My guess is there are several people here who would enjoy helping with such a useful algorithm.

Comment: Read his question carefully, especially this line "The answer is 2 : first A and second B, and first A and 5-th B." It's not just a simple substring search he is asking about.

Comment: @CharlieBurns - as usual, you are on top of things.  Thought you might be here, so I did not allocate any memory.  Yes answer needs some work.  I will look again.  lunch is almost over though!

Comment: thanks. It's not a trivial question. Good luck. May involve a finite state machine.

Comment: Thank you guys for sharing your thoughts. I am sorry I didn't make it clear enough. I add more details to it: "To be more specific, what I want is, the total number of ways of selecting A.size() elements from B such that there exists a permutation of the selected elements that matches B."

Comment: Well, my comments are too long for a comment, so see EDIT in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If X is a substring in Y, then each character of X must be in Y. So we first iterate through X and find the counts of each character, in an array `counts`.

Then for each character that has `count >= 1`, we count the number of times it appears in `Y` which can be done trivially in `O(n)`.

From here the answer should just be the multiplication of the combinations `C(count(Y),count(X))`.

If after the 3rd time reading your question I finally understand it correctly.